# How to get the name of the slack channel from conversation menu?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog, slack-block-kit

I have added a slack [conversation dropdown](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#conversation_select) and in the response I want to save/show channel name (or conversation name). I'm able to get the public channels information through [conversation.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info) API but for the private channels, I am not able to fetch any details. Can someone help me how I can get the names along with channel id (or conversation id).

This is the response from the slack on selecting a channel

> {'values': {'channel_block': {'selected_action_id': {'type': 'conversations_select', 'selected_conversation': 'G0*****JM'}}}}

Answer (score 0):

The token you're using to call `conversations.info` must have access to the channel in question before you can access it. I'm assuming it doesn't, but without seeing the response from the API I can't be sure.

Comment: You can only access public channels and to which you have been invited even you enabled all bot scopes. I can see only the private channel to which I have been invited or my personal channels and the same goes with the slack bot as well. 

I did a workaround to show a message to invite the bot first instead of going to the next step in which I want to display a channel name.